# Numerical decades: change to s or ies?

Tags: american-english, grammatical-number, numbers, time

As a native (American) English speaker, I change written decades to their numerical forms like the following:
Eighties = 80s, nineties = 90s

Throughout my time on the internet, though, I have seen a lot of second-language English speakers write decades ending in ies, like so:
Eighties = 80ies, nineties = 90ies

Is there any reason that this should be preferred?

Comment: Don't use "-ies" with numerals. And don't assume you see on the Internet is worth imitating, especially with respect to spelling.

Comment: @Robusto That's what I figured, but given that I don't think I ever learned a proper way to change them to numbers, it was worth an ask.

Comment: Good grief, no!  "80ies" is an abomination.

Comment: FWIW, the numeral+ies might be used on Twitter and any other limited-character-count sites to save characters.

Comment: @KristinaLopez, but doing it correctly would save two more characters.

Comment: 80ies is prounounced like this: eighty-ies. So your prounouncing the y twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common way to refer to decades is to add an “s” (without an apostrophe) after the number. Though there are [instances](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=80ies%2C90ies&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C80ies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C90ies%3B%2Cc0) of the "-ies" suffix being used after numbers to indicate decades, you should probably avoid it.

Per the ["Decades" page from the University of Otago's writing style guide](http://www.otago.ac.nz/writing-style/dates-numbers-contacts/otago635483.html):

> No apostrophe is required with the ‘s’ for decades when listed in full (e.g. 1990s). In situations where just the decade is indicated (e.g. ’80s) the direction of the leading apostrophe indicates that information ahead of the number “80” has been removed (i.e. it is a contraction of 1980 in this instance).
>
> 1990s
> 1840s
> ’80s

Comment: This works for me, echoes what everyone else has said, and backs up everything I've been doing already.